# Drawing a partial sprite with batch-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, sprites, spritebatch

I have a sprite like this.

[image]

I want to draw this sprite in such a way that sprite is growing from bottom to top, using sprite batch on tap.for that,I have written the following code:

```
  if (MyInputProcessor.isTap)
{
Sprite stickSprite = new Sprite(stickTexture);
stickSprite.setPosition(stick.getX(),stick.getY());
for(float n=0;n<100;n++)
{
     float i = 0.01f * n;
    batch.draw(
    stickSprite.getTexture(),
     stick.getX(),         
     stick.getY(),    
         stickSprite.getWidth() / 2,
         stickSprite.getHeight() / 2,            

         stickSprite.getWidth(),                                                   
         stickSprite.getHeight()*i,  //multiplying with height                                            
         stickSprite.getScaleX(),       
         stickSprite.getScaleY(),       
        0 ,                                    
        stickSprite.getRegionX(),      
        stickSprite.getRegionY(),      

        stickSprite.getRegionWidth(),
        stickSprite.getRegionHeight(), 
        false,
        false); 


 }
MyInputProcessor.isTap = false;
```

}

Here the i value increments but not taking effect in the code to scale.
Whats wrong with the code?

I tried this also:

```
   private void drawStick() { 

    Sprite stickSprite = new Sprite(stickTexture);

    if (MyInputProcessor.isTap)
    {
       stickSprite.setPosition(stick.getX(),stick.getY());
       for(float n=0;n<=100;n++)
       {
        float i = 0.01f * n;
        stickSprite.setSize(stickSprite.getWidth(),stickSprite.getHeight()+i);  
        }
    }
  stickSprite.draw(batch);
```

But rendering full sprite only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** You need to separe sprite's *initialization* and *display*

1. Make your sprite ONE time in your create method for example
2. Update your sprite's height on tap
3. Draw your sprite in your render method

---

Your code won't do what you want because you *make a new sprite at every tap*. You want to have a single sprite which you *resize in height at every tap*.

You should have something like this

```
// On tap
stickSprite.setSize(stickSprite.getWidth(), stickSprite.getHeight() + addValue);
```

This way you could draw your sprite easier like that

```
// On draw
stickSprite.draw(batch);
```

The setSize will resize your texture to the size you tell him. It will do it perfectly for your unicolor texture.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I tried this answer(included in the question now).Still it renders full sprite only.Please help me to find out whats wrong in it.

Comment: It's because you initialize your sprite at the same moment you draw it, so each tap, you'll have a NEW sprite that will erase the old one, i updated my answer to make it more clear